# Extract contents of Burn bootstrapper

Tags: wix, burn

I have an MSI package bundled in a WiX Burn bootstrapper. Can I extract this MSI from the bundle on the target machine?

Answer (score 37):

You need to use the `dark.exe` utility that comes with WiX.

```
dark.exe -x temp <installer>
```

Answer (score 5):

The bundle can't self-extract itself until someone implements [this feature](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3659/).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract an embedded .msi from your bundle while it's running if you're using a custom bootstrapper application, then extract the contents of that .msi by using the WiX SDK.

The short answer is that you can use the `Unbinder` class to extract the MSI files from your bundle:

```
unbinder = new Unbinder();
unbinder.Unbind(bundlePath, OutputType.Bundle, tmpFolder);
unbinder.DeleteTempFiles();
```

Then, use the `InstallPackge` class to extract the files:

```
using (var msiPackage = new InstallPackage(msiFilePath, DatabaseOpenMode.Transact) { WorkingDirectory = _targetFolder })
{
  using (var session = Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Installer.OpenPackage(msiPackage, ignoreMachineState: true))
  {
     msiPackage.ExtractFiles(fileKeysToInstall);
  }
  msiPackage.Close()
}
```

That's a very simplified version of what you need to do.  I've written a blog post with much more details, which you can find here:  http://www.wrightfully.com/extracting-msi-files-without-running-the-installer

Important Note: This does not run any of your custom actions, so makes sure to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting a WiX Toolset installation .exe package is easy.
Just use dark.exe from the [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/).

For example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\dark.exe c:\temp\myInstaller.exe -x c:\temp\myInstallerFiles
```